# How would I count MYSQL rows down to a specific row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, count, sql-order-by, row

I have a table that acts as a dropbox for files that get automatically queued.

I order the priority of files based on two things, the date and time, and if it has been verified or not.

Here is my query:

```
$dropcount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM queue WHERE status=2 OR status=3 
OR status=4 ORDER BY authorised DESC, timestamp DESC;");
```

What I need to do is count how many rows are ahead of the users current file because this will count every row, including the files behind the current users as well.

Thank you.

My table looks like this:

http://tabbidesign.com/table.png

The way this works is if a file is added its added to the queue. However if that file is authorised, it take priority over non verified files which means it needs to be counted even though it was added after some of the non verified flies.

The status column states if the file is:
-Being processed

-Queueing in the dropbox

-Cancelled by the user

-Cancelled by the admin

EDIT:
Ok @curtisdf's answer would work if I did the following:

```
$countauth =
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM queue
WHERE (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
AND authorised=1
AND timestamp < $timestamp

$countnorm =
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM queue
WHERE (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
AND authorised=0
AND timestamp < $timestamp

$actualcount = $countnorm + $countauth;
```

How could I merge this into one query, or is this not possible?

**THE SOLOUTION**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM queue WHERE (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)AND 
timestamp < $timestamp OR authorised=1
```

Found by @curtisdf.

Comment: What does your table look like? Couldn't you just put `WHERE timestamp<$file_time AND (status=2 OR ....)`?

Comment: My edit above has a link to my table. I don;t think I could do that because it also needs to take into account verified files, which may have been added after the current users.

Comment: Including an `ORDER BY` clause in a query that just extracts a `COUNT()` is not necessary.  The counting algorithm doesn't care about the order of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `idqueue` column is the primary key and it's auto-incremented, what about using it to filter out later ID's?  Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM queue 
WHERE status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4 
AND idqueue < $currentFileId
ORDER BY authorised DESC, timestamp DESC
```

EDIT: It's a little difficult to know how to answer because your table has so many columns and it's not clear what you're using all of them for.  What does the `status` column mean, for example, in contrast to the `authorized` column?  But anyway, since your `ORDER BY` doesn't matter for this query, and since you're looking for authorised files that came in prior to a given file, how about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM queue
WHERE (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
AND authorised=1
AND timestamp < $timestamp
```

EDIT 2: Okay, now I see what you're after.  :-)  If you just removed the "AND authorised=X" parts, I believe you could do it in one query.  This assumes your `authorised` column only would have values of `0` or `1`.  But if it has more than that, then you could do it by wrapping the `WHERE ... AND ...` parts of each query in their own parentheses, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM queue
WHERE (
    (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
    AND authorised=1
    AND timestamp < $timestamp
) OR (
    (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
    AND authorised=0
    AND timestamp < $timestamp
)
```

This could be simplified even further:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM queue
WHERE (status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4)
AND timestamp < $timestamp
AND (authorised=1 OR authorised=0)
```

Comment: The problem is is that an authorised file may be added after the current file. This means that that authorised file would not be counted when it is actually ahead of the current one. This is because authorised files get prioritised.

Comment: Okay I think I see more clearly.  I've edited my answer in light of some new thoughts.

Comment: Ok I have added more information to my post, your answer has nearly worked but it would have to be in two querys then added together. How could I add this into one? Thanks you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The only thing with your code that didn't work was that the AND authorised, needed an OR instead. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in a where statement:

```
$dropcount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM queue WHERE (status=2 OR status=3
OR status=4) AND authorised=1 and timestamp<'$currentUserTimeStamp'  ORDER BY 
authorised DESC, timestamp DESC;");
```

If you don't know the current user timestamp, you'll need to select that first.

```
$result = mysql_query("select `timestamp` from queue where (status=2 or status=3 or 
status=4) and `userid`='$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$currentUserTimeStamp = $row[0];
```

Of course, I've made up the column name for the user id.

Comment: Ok this is very close to working, but it only displays authorised files.

Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly, but all files are added to the queue. Authorised files are prioritised over normal files.

Would I have to use two query's?

Comment: Just get rid of the `authorised=1`

Comment: Yes but any authorised files added after the current user should be ahead of the current user. The time stamp will be newer but it should be counted because it is prioritised.

Comment: Instead of `authorised=1 and timestamp<'$currentUserTimeStamp'` just make your conditional `(authorised=1 OR timestamp<'$currentUserTimeStamp'))` .